# jquery clearTimeout() misbehavior in Firefox only

Tags: jquery

This code (some sort of tooltip) works great in IE, opera, chrome, safari. But not in Firefox.
I think the problem lies in the clearTimeout() function. Does anyone knows what is wrong?

Thank you!

```
$('.go_info').live("mouseenter", function(e){

    var q_tooltip_img = $(this).attr('id');
    tm = setTimeout( function(){
       $("#tooltip_"+q_tooltip_img).show();

       }, 1000);
    tm_img = setTimeout( function(){
       $("#tooltip_img_"+q_tooltip_img).empty().html('<div class="PP_wait_loading"></div>');
        $("#tooltip_img_"+q_tooltip_img).load("PP_small_preview.php?ID="+q_tooltip_img);
       }, 1000);    

}); 

$('.go_info').live("mouseleave",function(){
      clearTimeout(tm);
      clearTimeout(tm_img);
      var q_tooltip_img = $(this).attr('id');
      $("#tooltip_"+q_tooltip_img).hide();   

});
```

So, this script makes a div show up when the mouse enters the go_info div. And have to go away as soon as the mouse leaves the go_info div.
This works well with all browsers, exept from FF, this just shows some flickering of the div.

Comment: And what is the problem? What does not work? What do you expect to happen and what does actually happen?

Comment: `tm` and `tm_img` should be global variables.

Comment: Felix, you are right, I should be more specific

Answer (score 1):

This code assumes that `tm` and `tm_img` are global variables.  It also assumes that there is only one object in your page with a class of `.go_info` because if there is more than one object with that class then multiple event handlers are all trying to use the same global variables and they may mess each other up.

A much safer version of the code would be something like this (variables are now local variables and timers are stored persistently per DOM object rather than in global variables):

```
$('.go_info').live("mouseenter", function(e){
    var q_tooltip_img = $(this).attr('id');
    var tm = setTimeout( function(){
       $("#tooltip_"+q_tooltip_img).show();
       }, 1000);
    $(this).data("tm", tm); 
    var tm_img = setTimeout( function(){
       $("#tooltip_img_"+q_tooltip_img).empty().html('<div class="PP_wait_loading"></div>');
        $("#tooltip_img_"+q_tooltip_img).load("PP_small_preview.php?ID="+q_tooltip_img);
       }, 1000);    
    $(this).data("tm_img", tm_img);
}); 

$('.go_info').live("mouseleave",function(){
      clearTimeout($(this).data("tm"));
      clearTimeout($(this).data("tm_img"));
      var q_tooltip_img = $(this).attr('id');
      $("#tooltip_"+q_tooltip_img).hide();   
});
```

Other things that could be wrong here:

1. You don't show us your HTML and you are doing some id string manipulation so it's possible that you don't have the IDs quite right to make this `$("#tooltip_"+q_tooltip_img)` work right.
2. You are setting two timeouts for the exact same time (1 second) which seems odd.  Why two timeouts?  Why not just set one and do both pieces of work in the one?
3. You should definitely put either a breakpoint or console.log() lines in the mouseleave function and verify that it's getting called when you expect and that it's finding the $("#tooltip_"+q_tooltip_img) object.

As you can see in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/74MYg/), the base concept works with the ID manipulation if everything is done right.  If you still can't figure it out, I'd suggest you post the relevant HTML.

Comment: this makes sense, but still, it only works with everything except FF. I've the impressing that the mouseleave may cause the problem?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint or console.log() in the mouseleave function?  Is it getting called and just not working?  Or not getting called at all?

Comment: I updated my answer with some other thoughts and a jsFiddle that shows it working.

Comment: jfriend00, thank you so much for your effort, I work on this later today and keep you posted. much appreciated!